# How does onSelect(hero: Hero) modify heroes=HEROES in angular tour heroes tutorial

Tags: angular

HeroesComponent class:

heroes=[ [{ id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },{ id: 12, name: 'Narco' },{ id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }]

```
    onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
      this.selectedHero = hero;         /*How does this modify heroes model*/
    }
```

If I select  id: 20, name: 'Tornado' then this.selectedHero = { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }.

How does this change the heroes model. How is the connection made between this.selectedHero and heroes. I don't see any setters changing the model? Isn't this.selectedHero an object in itself?

Comment: I don't see the code snippet that you posted in angular.io tour of heroes tutorial. can help post the link url? And you're right, by looking at this code snippet, it only changes the selectedHero object only, not heroes.

Comment: Here is the link. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 Please refer to the Final Code review section at the bottom of the page. the code located in heroes.component.ts .Thank you

Comment: i finally get what you are asking. please check my answer @Snm

Answer (score 1):

It's not Angular but it's more about Javascript Object mutation.

Javascript objects are referenced by memory if assigned to another variable.
If one of the parameters of that variable is updated, it automatically updates the original object because of the memory reference.

You can read up more about this here.
https://alistapart.com/article/why-mutation-can-be-scary/

Therefore if you do like this

```
const heroes = [{id:1,name:"Kevin"},{id:2,name:"David"}];
const selectedHero = heroes[1];
selectedHero.name = "George"
```

Finally, it will result in heroes as

```
[{id:1,name:"Kevin"},{id:2,name:"George"}]
```

Since in your sample, `this.selectedHero` is directly assigned an item inside the `heroes` array, it still has the memory reference and if `this.selectedHero` is updated, it will mutate the heroes array also.